# read stdout and stderr from subprocess line by line simulanously without one select() per line

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess

I want to start a subprocess in Python and output the subprocess's stdout and stderr in real time. With two or more pipes this can get difficult due the blocking nature of `read()` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command).

As shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12272262/1668622) answer this is possible, though:

```
    FDs = [process.stdout.fileno(),
           process.stderr.fileno()]

    while True:
        ret = select.select(FDs, [], [])

        for fd in ret[0]:
            if fd == process.stdout.fileno():
                print(process.stdout.readline())
            if fd == process.stderr.fileno():
                print(process.stderr.readline())
```

And this is *nearly* what I'm looking for if not `select()` was so damn slow. Compared to reading without select() (after process termination) the output is being slowed down by factor 50x or more (tested on `find`).

If I tried to use select() but always read the whole buffer e.g. by using `readlines()` I run into the first problem with blocking reads and reading one pipe will avoid reading the other.

I could start a reader thread for each pipe but this would ugly and complicated since I had to make sure the threads are being terminated correctly.

**So my question is:** do you know an elegant way to read from more than one pipe in the same thread? Maybe there is something like `read_available_lines()` which would check the buffer size or something similar.

Comment: Linux only: you could try select.epoll() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194018/wait-the-end-of-subprocesses-with-multiple-parallel-jobs

Comment: If it is a performance question then a benchmark could help. There is no silver bullet: to read two pipes concurrently, you need either explicit threads or a select-like solution (select, poll, epoll, kqueue, iocp). See [Subprocess.Popen: cloning stdout and stderr both to terminal and variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17190221/4279)

Comment: See also, [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/375427/4279). Check whether `fcntl`-based approach works in your case.