# Simultaneously wait() for multiple subproccess.Popen commands, then exit

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I'm trying to run an unknown number of commands and capture their stdout in a file. However, I am presented with a difficulty when attempting to `p.wait()` on each instance. My code looks something like this:

```
print "Started..."
for i, cmd in enumerate(commands):
    i = "output_%d.log" % i
    p = Popen(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=open(i, 'w'))
    p.wait()
print "Done!"
```

I'm looking for a way to execute everything in `commands` simultaneously and exit the current script **only** when each and every single process has been completed. It would also help to be informed when each command returns an exit code.

I've looked at some answers, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288) by J.F. Sebastian and tried to adapt it to my situation by changing `args=(p.stdout, q)` to `args=(p.returncode, q)` but it ended up exiting immediately and running in the background (possibly due to `shell=True`?), as well as not responding to any keys pressed inside the bash shell... I don't know where to go with this.

[Jeremy Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3195673) also helped, sort of, but `select.epoll()` was throwing an AttributeError exception.

Is there any other seamless way or trick to make it work? It doesn't need to be cross platform, a solution for GNU/Linux and macOS would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big thanks to Adam Matan for the [biggest hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31831031) towards the solution. This is what I came up with, and it works flawlessly:

1. It initiates each `Thread` object in parallel
2. It starts each instance simultaneously
3. Finally it waits for each exit code without blocking other threads

Here is the code:

```
import threading
import subprocess

...

def run(cmd):
    name = cmd.split()[0]
    out = open("%s_log.txt" % name, 'w')
    err = open('/dev/null', 'w')
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=out, stderr=err)
    p.wait()
    print name + " completed, return code: " + str(p.returncode)

...

proc = [threading.Thread(target=run, args=(cmd)) for cmd in commands]
[p.start() for p in proc]
[p.join() for p in proc]
print "Done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have rathered add this as a comment because I was working off of Jack of all Spades' answer.  I had trouble getting that exact command to work because it was unpacking the string list I had of commands.

Here's my edit for python3:

```
import subprocess
import threading

commands = ['sleep 2', 'sleep 4', 'sleep 8']

def run(cmd):
    print("Command %s" % cmd)
    name = cmd.split(' ')[0]
    print("name %s" % name)
    out = open('/tmp/%s_log.txt' % name, 'w')
    err = open('/dev/null', 'w')
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=out, stderr=err)
    p.wait()
    print(name + " completed, return code: " + str(p.returncode))


proc = [threading.Thread(target=run, kwargs={'cmd':cmd}) for cmd in commands]
[p.start() for p in proc]
[p.join() for p in proc]
print("Done!")
```